# Regex for matching a SELECT sql query

Tags: sql, regex

I have some sql select queries and I want to extract all those statements wherein a given set of columns (say A,B,C) is being selected from a given table (say X). The regex should be able to match

```
select A,B,C,D,E from X,Y,Z,(select * from R)
select B,C,A from Y,X
```

I tried something like this:

```
select(?=.*\sA)(?=.*\sB)(?=.*\sC).*\sfrom(?=.*\sX).*
```

but it also matches scenarios like

```
select D from X,(select A,B,C) from Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
select [ABCD,]{3,} from X.*
```

Assuming that you want to select statements which are selecting more then 2 coloumns